# Filter struct array within a struct

Tags: swift

Let's say you have an array of Car structs, which incorporates an array of previous owners.

```
struct Car {
   var model: String // Ford Taurus
   var owners: [Owner]
}

struct Owner {
   var name: String // Harrison Ford
   var location: String // Oxford
}
```

When people search for "Ford" I want to check the Car model as well as the Owner name and location for the word 'ford'. I know how to filter the Car model, but not the Owner properties.

```
let filteredCars = cars.filter { (car) -> Bool in
            return car.model.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased())
        }
```

How do I filter the owner properties as well?

Answer (score 2):

Do a double filter with `or`, for the owner I joined both properties before searching since it doesn't matter which one that matches

```
let searchKey = "Ford".lowercased()
let selected = cars.filter({
    $0.model.lowercased().contains(searchKey) ||
    $0.owners.contains(where: {"\($0.name) ($0.location)".lowercased().contains(searchKey)})})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
let filteredCars = cars.filter {
    return $0.model.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased()) ||
           !$0.owners.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(textToSearch.lowercased())}.isEmpty

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all two conversions to lowercase per iteration is not very efficient.

Better use `range(of` with option `.caseInsensitive`.

```
let filteredCars = cars.filter { (car) -> Bool in
    return car.model.range(of: textToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
    !car.owners.filter({"\($0.name) \($0.location)".range(of: textToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}).isEmpty
}
```